# Retrieve a VPC to create a security group

Tags: pulumi

I'm trying to get back a VPC and then create a security group with rules in it. I have been following the steps [here in their docs](https://pulumi.io/reference/crosswalk/aws/vpc/#getting-the-default-vpc) however I need to get a vpc that isn't the default vpc.

I have code like so:

```
const primaryVpcId = config.require("primaryVpcId");

const primaryVpc = awsx.ec2.Vpc.fromExistingIds("primary", {
    vpcId: primaryVpcId
}); 

const sg = new awsx.ec2.SecurityGroup("jcsg", {vpc:primaryVpc});
```

The problem is the `primaryVpc` object is empty so when I run `pulumi up` it errors saying the subnet ids are empty. I know there is nothing wrong with the vpc in aws so the retrieving of it is failing somehow.

Comment: You've tried it with the newest [`@pulumi/awsx` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pulumi/awsx) version `0.18.6`? I can't reproduce the error even with `0.17.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the docs it looks like when using the `fromExistingIds` you have to specify subresource ids as well. If you're planning on using subnets you'll have to pass in the ids for those too they don't appear to be autodiscovered.

*Get an existing Vpc resource's state with the given name and IDs of its relevant sub-resources. This will not cause a VPC (or any sub-resources) to be created, and removing this Vpc from your pulumi application will not cause the existing cloud resource (or sub-resources) to be destroyed.*

```
const importedVpc = awsx.ec2.Vpc.fromExistingIds('primary', {
    vpcId: 'theId',
    privateSubnetIds: ['id1', 'id2']
})
```

I imagine you'd have to do the same for any of the properties from `ExistingVpcIdArgs` (the second parameter to the function) that you plan to use elsewhere in the program.

Comment: Well that seems dumb, the whole point of getting the vpc from it's id is for the api to then return everything about it including the sub resources :). Thanks

Comment: @Jon Feel free to upvote or approve this as the answer if it works for you. Obviously not the answer you were looking for but could be helpful to others in the community